# Sending SES template email returns "The template data is invalid while trying to pass the values in the TemplateData

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

Please help on this scenario. I am preparing a script which has one "for" loop & that will work user by user basis. I just want to use the SES Template to send mail to each user.

How can i pass the user name & the password age to the script in TemplateData.

```
email_alert = ses.send_templated_email(
Source=email_from,
Destination={
'ToAddresses': [
'user_mail',
]
},
Template='SES-TEMPLATE-Password-Warning',
TemplateData='{"name": "username", "password_expires": "password_expires_in"}'
)*
```

Where the "username" is the IAM user name which can be fetched from the excel file using "row['user']" and i calculated the age using below formula and i just need to add these values in the above template data.

```
last_changed_date=dateutil.parser.parse(row['password_last_changed']).date()
expires = (last_changed_date + datetime.timedelta(MaxPasswordAge)) - datetime.date.today()
password_expires_in = expires.days
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding two lines for converting the required values `row['user']` & `password_expires` to string .i.e. `user_name=str(row['user'])` and `password_expires_in = str(password_expires)` and then passed the values using format `"'+user_name+'"` and `"'+password_expires_in+'"` in the TemplateData.

Now the SES Template Data format used here is:

```
TemplateData='{"name": "'+user_name+'", "password_expires": "'+password_expires_in+'"}')
```